# How to handle the return type of dispatch with Redux Promise Middleware?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-promise-middleware

Redux Promise Middleware seems to handle the promise resolution of an action payload. For example, consider this action creator that uses a `Promise` as payload:

```ts
export default class ActionCreators {
  public static fetchAllUsers(): FetchAction {
    return {
      type: actionTypes.FETCH_ALL_USERS,
      payload: fetch("api.com/users")
    };
  }
}
```

When using this action creator, TypeScript expects an `Action` returned data, instead of the `Promise` that is actually returned because of redux-promise-middleware.

So the following code will not compile because `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Action'.`

```ts
dispatch(ActionCreators.fetchAllUsers())
    .then(response => {
        // do something with response
    })
```

Typescript expects returned properties like `payload` and `type`, which are actually not returned because the promise has been handled already and has ACTUALLY been returned.

`.then` is ready to be used, but typescript will not compile because it expects something else.

I guess the question is: How to write the correct typings to handle redux-promise-middleware actions, while providing redux' `connect`-function with the correct dispatch types for `mapDispatchToProps` etc.

Comment: I'm pretty new to redux, but doesn't this violate the pure function principle of redux? If the payload is a promise that fetches data from a server, then the reducer that processes this payload can't be a pure function, since the results aren't deterministic.

Comment: This is true. And this makes it even more annoying that there's no clear way to use this middleware. We're considering just moving on to an other solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I encountered the very same problem, and I couldn't find a solution. In my case, I cannot use `dispatch(...).catch` notation. it says `Type error: Property 'catch' does not exist on type '{ type: string; payload(): Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>; }'`

Comment: @wired_in no, because the middleware swallows that original action containing the promise payload, dispatches an immediate `PENDING` action, then later a `FULFILLED` / `REJECTED` action depending on what happens with that promise. These actions are all pure and deterministic, and they're the ones that actually go through to the reducers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional types.
E.g.

```
export interface BaseAction<TPayload> {
   type: string;
   payload: TPayload;
}

export interface Dispatch {
    <T extends BaseAction<any>>(action: T): 
         T extends BaseAction<Promise<infer R>> ? Promise<R>:  T
```

}